# CSS overflow-y is not working in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have created a custom html CSS code that I'd like to use in wordpress
the code works fine on my local server but when I push it to the custom html block it doesn't work the same.
I use the flatsome theme
my html code is

```
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <!-- <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="empty-space"></div>
        <h3 class="title">Limited only by imagination</h3>
        <div class="main-down-div">
            <div class="main-div">
                <div class="scroll-div">
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h4 class="sub-title">Taste The Freshness Of Herbs</h4>
                            <div class="content-images">
                                <img src="Lemon-Balm.png">
                                <img src="Lemon-Balm.png">
                                <img src="Lemon-Balm.png">
                                <img src="Lemon-Balm.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h4 class="sub-title">Grow Your Own Edibles</h4>
                            <div class="content-images">
                                <img src="Spinach.png">
                                <img src="Strawberries.png">
                                <img src="Sunflower.png">
                                <img src="Thyme.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h4 class="sub-title">Eat Healthy Microgreens</h4>
                            <div class="content-images">
                                <img src="Spinach.png">
                                <img src="Strawberries.png">
                                <img src="Sunflower.png">
                                <img src="Thyme.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h4 class="sub-title">Liven Up Your Space</h4>
                            <div class="content-images">
                                <img src="Spinach.png">
                                <img src="Strawberries.png">
                                <img src="Sunflower.png">
                                <img src="Thyme.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
body{
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
}
.main-div{
    background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
    position: relative;
}
.title{
    text-align: center;
}
.sub-title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #404040;
}
.content-container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.content{
    margin: 0 0 10%;
}
.content-images{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.content-images img{
    width: 15%;
}
.scroll-div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */    
}
.main-div::after{
    content: '';
    height: 125px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(237, 237, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0) 100%);
}
.main-down-div{
    position: relative;
}
.main-down-div::after{
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(237, 237, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0) 100%);
}
.scroll-div{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 70%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

.empty-space{
    height: 100px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .scroll-div{
        padding-top: 10%;
        padding-bottom: 20%;
    }
    .content-images img{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .title{
        font-size: 8vw;
    }
    .sub-title{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 6vw;
    }
    .scroll-div{
        height: 75%;
    }
    .empty-space{
        height: 0px;
    }
}
```

when I put this code in the custom html block on wordpress
the **overflow-y: scroll;** doesn't work for **.scroll-div**
I have also tried to use **overflow-y: scroll !important;** but it doesn't help
I believe that there is something that is not blocking my code

[this is how my code looks on my local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r29Vg.png)

[this is how my output is when I add this code to a custom block on wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6nzm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your content is long enough to warrant scrolling? I took your code and added `max-height: 20rem;` to `.scroll-div` and it scrolled as I'd imagine you'd like it to.

For reference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

> Defines the height as a percentage of the containing block's height.

It's possible the containing block is insufficiently defined such that your 70% height creates hard boundaries, triggering the scroll effect you're looking for.

It'd likely be easier to diagnose seeing it on the live site.

Comment: yes I'm sure the content is long enough when I add the images the size increases, like I said it works fine on my local server. its just the doesn't work on my wordpress

Comment: I'm sorry, that disconnect between local and production sounds frustrating. I'd be interested to poke around if there's a link to see it in WP. I'm sorry I'm can't be more helpful.